# How to implement Majority Vote

Tags: qiskit, quantum-algorithms, error-correction, quantum-phase-estimation

I am trying to boost the success probability of standard phase estimation by repeating the procedure enough times and taking a majority vote that will be encoded in a quantum register.
My problem is I don't know how to implement a majority vote.

For 3 qubits $a$, $b$ and $c$ taken in $\{|0\rangle, |1\rangle \}$ the majority vote circuit returns $MV(a, b, c)$ and can be implemented as follows:

[image: Majority vote 3 qubits]

For example, if $a$, $b$ and $c$ are all in state $|0\rangle$ or if $b$ or $c$ are in state $|1\rangle$ then nothing happens and $MV(a, b, c) = a$. If $b$ and $c$ are in $|1\rangle$, the CCNOT gate flips $a$.

If $a$, $b$ and $c$ are in state $|+\rangle$, then $MV(a, b, c) = |+\rangle$ and we have 50% probability for each outcome.

How can we generalize this circuit to 5 qubits and higher ?

([My motivation is to implement this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3ieC.jpg))

Comment: I am also looking into this majority-voting operation but for another motivation. Have you made any progress since the post?